# Iteration in Rails form_for is adding all instances of model on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iteration, form-for

I have an `Order` and `Items`, with join table `OrderItems` that act as line items in an order. In `order#show`, I want to display all instances of `Items` and be able to add this to the order through creating a new `OrderItem`. The issue is that when I post the form, `order_item#create` makes 40 new `order_items` for all `Items`, instead of just creating one instance of `OrderItem` for that one item I want to add.

Here is the `OrderItems` controller:

```
def create
    @order_item = @order.order_items.build(order_item_params)

    if @order_item.save
        flash[:notice] = "Your item was added"
        redirect_to [@user, @order]
    else
        flash[:error] = "Your item was not added. Please try again."
        redirect_to [@user, @order]
    end
end
```

Here is the form in `order#show`

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
    <div>
        <%= form_for [@user, @order, @order.order_items.create(:item_id => item.id)] do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label item.name %>
                <%= f.label "$#{item.price.to_s}" %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label 'quantity' %>
                <%= f.text_area :quantity %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label 'item id' %>
                <%= f.text_area :item_id %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.submit 'Add Item', class: 'btn' %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the `order_item#create` action isn't creating the 40 `order_items`. It's your form:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @order, @order.order_items.create(:item_id => item.id)] do |f| %>
```

Change the `create` to `build` and that way it won't save the 40 instances. It will only save the one you hit submit for.